# Transformation Constraint - Can't map location to rotation

Tags: constraints

I am unable to use an object Transformation constraint to map a location to a rotation. The [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/transformation.html#) says I should be able to do it, but it is not working.

Here is a simple example. The *Cube* has a constraint to transform the *Empty* object's location to a rotation:

[image: Setup]

The constraint on *Cube*:

[image]

Note that the first image shows the *Empty* y location is between 3 and 4, so the rotation of *Cube* should be something other than 0. Moving the *Empty* doesn't do anything to *Cube*.

What am I missing, please?

Update: I'm using version 2.92.0

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the cube's Z rotation is supposed to be influenced by the  empty's Y location, you need to set the *Z Source Axis* to Y:

[image]

Comment: Makes total sense! Thanks!